# How do I parse the sentence of have + past particple + to be + adjective?

Tags: tense

**e.g.
General audiences have proven to be more appreciative of director Alvin Stern's movies than professional film critics.**

Currently I can't parse **have proven to be more appreciative** of above sentence.

Can anyone explain it me?

Comment: Is it the syntactic structure, i.e. constituents, categories and functions that you want to know?

Comment: **Parse?** The "general audiences" have proven something (shown something to be true) and the thing that has been proven to be true (by the general audiences) is their (the general audiences') more appreciative action/emotions toward Alvin Stern's movies. "have proven" is the action of "general audiences," and "being more appreciative" is what they have proven of themselves. If this doesn't answer your question please further explain the issue you are having. This is a common phrase "proven to be" meaning someone (or something) has shown themself to have a specific attribute.

Comment: This definition of "prove to be ______" from a quick search may help: 1. To show or provide evidence of having a particular trait, attribute, or characteristic. __The new method proved to be effective.__

Comment: I meant **parse** here with understanding the meaning of the sentence rather analyzing    anything other stuff.

Comment: @EliHarold your explanations are really helpful for me.

Comment: @electricalapprentice Are you now saying it's the meaning you're interested in, not the grammatical parse?

Comment: @BillJ Mainly the meaning , secondary grammatical parse. I may had misunderstood the meaning of "parse".

Comment: I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

> *have proven to be more appreciative*

If it's just how to parse (analyse) the expression that you want to know, then:

The whole expression is a verb phrase functioning as predicate of the sentence.

"Have" is the matrix verb, which has the subordinate clause "proven to be more appreciative" as its complement.

That subordinate clause has "proven" as its head verb, which has the further subordinate clause "to be more appreciative" as its complement.

The bracketing is like this:

> [*have* [*proven* [*to be more appreciative*]]]

Sentence like the one you cite are commonly called catenative constructions.